# Jmeter Distribution Testing - Requirement of Software versions

Tags: jmeter

Im tryig to do Distribution Testing
Im starting the remote testing witout running create-rmi-keystore.bat file as we are enabling the config "server_ssi_rmi_disable=true" to avoid key generation.
Observing the below error message in Jmeter server log of Slave system.

````
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is: 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.<init>(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.startServer(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:441) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259) ~[ApacheJMeter.jar:5.5]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.loadStore(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:147) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:99) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]```

Software versions are in my System :

In master and Slave Jmeter version is 5.5.
In Master system the Java version 1.8.0_241  and Slave System the Java Version is 1.8.0_251

This will affect the communication between master and slave ? 



Tried to Test the distributed testing with multiple system. But observing Listening port failures. Need to reslove the same.
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't think minor differences in Java version really matter, however when possible I'm trying to use **exactly the same software** to avoid any inconsistencies.

With regards to the error you're getting - it looks like you simply forgot to create the RMI keystore with the certificates so JMeter master-slave bidirectional communication would be encrypted. Follow instructions from [Setting up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) documentation chapter.

> Since JMeter 4.0 the default transport mechanism for RMI will use SSL. SSL needs keys and certificates to work. You will have to create those keys yourself.
>
> The simplest setup is to use one key/cert pair for all JMeter servers and clients you want to connect. JMeter comes with a script to generate a keystore that contains one key (and its corresponding certificate) named `rmi`. The script is located in the bin directory and is available for Windows systems (called `bin/create-rmi-keystore.bat`) and Unix like systems (called `bin/create-rmi-keystore.sh`). It will generate a key-pair, that is valid for seven days, with a default passphrase of value `'changeit'`. It is advised to call it from inside the bin directory.

If you don't care about the communication between master and slaves being secure you can simply turn it off by adding the next line to *user.properties* file on all JMeter instances involved into the distributed configuration:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)